# Trying to print total space in bytes in directory and all sub directories

Tags: c, unix, directory

I'm currently trying to make a c program that counts the total file size in bytes of a given directory, including the directory itself, all files within, and all files and directories in all sub-directories. Essentially, I'm being asked to program a replacement for `du -b` as a command.

I thought I had a working solution, but after the first directory this program thinks that all entries deeper down are directories, even when they're just regular files. This includes when I give it a directory that's one degree deeper directly, say by giving it the input `./Directory1` instead of just `.`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int du_function(char direc[]) {
    int total = 0;
    char str[100];
    strcpy(str, direc);
    struct stat sfile;
    struct dirent *de;
    DIR *dr = opendir(direc);
    if (dr == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open directory\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", de->d_name);
        stat(de->d_name, &sfile);
        if (S_ISDIR(sfile.st_mode) && strcmp(de->d_name, ".") != 0 &&
            strcmp(de->d_name, "..") != 0) {
            strcat(str, "/");
            strcat(str, de->d_name);
            printf("This is a directory called %s\n", str);
            total = total + du_function(str);
            strcpy(str, direc);
        }
        if (S_ISREG(sfile.st_mode) || strcmp(de->d_name, ".") == 0) {
            printf("Size in bytes = %ld\n", sfile.st_size);
            total = total + sfile.st_size;
            printf("The total is %d bytes so far.\n", total);
        }
    }
    printf("The total is %d bytes.\n", total);
    closedir(dr);
    return total;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        char cwd[1] = ".";
        du_function(cwd);
    } else
        du_function(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm at my wit's end here and have tried a variety of solutions, but for some reason `S_ISDIR` must be identifying things as directories that aren't (or receiving the wrong input from me, more likely.)

Comment: Aside: recommend a more generous type for `total` such as `unsigned long long total`.

Comment: @Magugag: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 0):

`char cwd[1] = ".";` is too small for a *string*.  No room the the *null character*.

Use `[]` and let the compiler determine the needed size for the *string*.

```
char cwd[] = ".";
```

---

`stat()` call is based on local name and not full path.

```
#if 0
    stat(de->d_name, &sfile);
#else
    char buf[500];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s/%s", direc, de->d_name);
    stat(buf, &sfile);
#endif
```

Similar finding in (deleted) [@PSkocik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55093292/2410359)

---

Perhaps other issues exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you construct the path for the recursive call, you must construct the filename with the leading directory for the `stat` system call. Your program only works for the files in the current directory.

An effective way to fix your program is pass a large enough buffer to the recursive function and build the path and filenames incrementally in place:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>

long int du_function(char path[], size_t size) {
    size_t len = strlen(path);
    long int total = 0;
    struct stat sfile;
    struct dirent *de;
    DIR *dr = opendir(path);
    if (dr == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open directory %s\n", path);
        return 0;
    }
    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(de->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        //printf("%s\n", de->d_name);
        if (snprintf(path + len, size - len, "/%s", de->d_name) > (int)(size - len)) {
            path[len] = '\0';
            printf("Path too long: %s/%s\n", path, de->d_name);
            continue;
        }
        stat(path, &sfile);
        if (S_ISDIR(sfile.st_mode) && strcmp(de->d_name, ".") != 0) {
            //printf("This is a directory called %s\n", path);
            total = total + du_function(path, size);
        } else
        if (S_ISREG(sfile.st_mode) || strcmp(de->d_name, ".") == 0) {
            //printf("Size in bytes = %ld\n", (long)sfile.st_size);
            total = total + sfile.st_size;
            //printf("The total is %ld bytes so far.\n", total);
        }
    }
    path[len] = '\0';
    printf("%ld\t%s\n", total, path);
    closedir(dr);
    return total;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char path[1024] = ".";
    if (argc > 1) {
        strcpy(path, argv[1]);
    }
    du_function(path, sizeof path);
    return 0;
}
```